# How to process json Observable

Tags: json, angular

I'm receiving a complicated Object sent from my Express back-end, using `res.json`. (A list of members who have registered).

On the front-end, I'd like to convert the json response into an object that I can process in my template. Shouldn't I just be able to call JSON.parse() on the json response?

I've seen some proposed solutions that require the HttpClient `get` call to have a generic of the type of the object to be returned, i.e. `get<MyObj>`. (such as in this article [Angular Http Call](https://davidpine.net/blog/angular-http-gotchas/)). Is there a way to do this without specifying in advance the return type from the `get` call? (I'd like to keep the front-end implementation as light and flexible as possible, and do all the data definitions in the back-end, then use the front-end to "read" the back-end data structure. The data structure is quite complicated and long, and it would save a lot of work if I can avoid repeating the data definition in both the back and front end).

Unfortunately, I haven't found a way yet, as for instance the editor tells me that JSON.parse expects a string parameter, while my HttpClient call returns an Object.

Here's the code I have so far:

`member.service.ts:`

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.getList();
}

getList(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http
      .get(`${this.host_url}list`,{responseType: 'json'})
  }
```

`register.component.ts`

```
users$: Observable<Object>;

getUsers() {
    this.users$ = this.member.getList();
  }
```

`register.component.html`

```
<ul>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let user of users$ | async ">
    <li>
      {{user | json}}  <-- This gives me a string. If I use {{ user }} without the json pipe, I get an object, but can't reference its properties.
    </li>
  </ng-container>
</ul>
```

Currently, in my `ngFor*` loop, I'm unable to grab the `user` object and reference it's properties (i.e. `user.authData[0].username`). How can I modify my code to be able to reference `user`'s properties in the template? Do I have to provide the data type in advance to the `get` call, or is there another way?

EDIT (1): Here is some sample data returned by the `{{ user | json }}` pipe:

```
 { "_id": "5cf1b7792ecf136bd4cddebf", "authData": [], "nameData": [], "emailData": [], "phoneData": [], "addressData": [], "companyData": [], "idData": [], "photoData": [], "memberData": [], "creditCardData": [], "__v": 0 }
{ "_id": "5cf207038e3f2551dcf4c803", "authData": [], "nameData": [], "emailData": [], "phoneData": [], "addressData": [], "companyData": [], "idData": [], "photoData": [], "memberData": [], "creditCardData": [], "__v": 0 }
{ "_id": "5d6ff6ac7046a519403c801f", "authData": [], "nameData": [], "emailData": [], "phoneData": [], "addressData": [], "companyData": [], "idData": [], "photoData": [], "memberData": [], "creditCardData": [], "__v": 0 }
{ "_id": "5d7015dddba7384d64540571", "authData": [], "nameData": [], "emailData": [], "phoneData": [], "addressData": [], "companyData": [], "idData": [], "photoData": [], "memberData": [], "creditCardData": [], "__v": 0 }
{ "_id": "5d7061fd767c8c41202f49b7", "authData": [], "nameData": [], "emailData": [], "phoneData": [], "addressData": [], "companyData": [], "idData": [], "photoData": [], "memberData": [], "creditCardData": [], "__v": 0 }
{ "_id": "5d71b9b1fa4fb10afc346323", "authData": [], "nameData": [], "emailData": [], "phoneData": [], "addressData": [], "companyData": [], "idData": [], "photoData": [], "memberData": [], "creditCardData": [], "__v": 0 }
{ "_id": "5d71bcd2fa4fb10afc346332", "authData": [], "nameData": [], "emailData": [], "phoneData": [], "addressData": [], "companyData": [], "idData": [], "photoData": [], "memberData": [], "creditCardData": [], "__v": 0 }
{ "_id": "5d71bf76fa4fb10afc34633e", "authData": [], "nameData": [], "emailData": [], "phoneData": [], "addressData": [], "companyData": [], "idData": [], "photoData": [], "memberData": [], "creditCardData": [], "__v": 0 }
{ "_id": "5d71ce7d52a93e0700f2c052", "authData": [], "nameData": [], "emailData": [], "phoneData": [], "addressData": [], "companyData": [], "idData": [], "photoData": [], "memberData": [], "creditCardData": [], "__v": 0 }
```

Comment: can you share with us the api respond ?

Comment: you don't need to set the response type to json it set by default and parse the response

Comment: what this return ` {{user | json}} ` string like what ?

Comment: I edited the original post to add the `{{ user | json }}` return string. Please see above, Tks!

Comment: you can loop throw `*ngFor="let date of user.authData"` this will print authData data

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing happens when I do that:
`<ng-container *ngFor="let user of users$ | async ">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let data of user.authData">
  <li>
    {{data}}
  </li>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>`

Comment: but your sample data is empty ? if there is data you will see a result

Comment: Good point! Let me check and update you shortly!

Comment: The data sample is not empty . . . There is data there, but it's not showing. The data structure is user.authData[0].username.value. I tried `let data of user.authData` with `{{data[0].username.value}}` and `let data of user.authData[0]`, with `{{data.username.value}}` but neither worked. I also took away the `value`, and normally if there's an object, it will render in the browser as ` [object Object]`, but it was just blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**member.service.ts:**

```
getUsers(): Observable<any[]> {
  return this.httpClient
    .get<any[]>(`${environment.api_url}/api/users`)
    .pipe(map(data => data));}
```

**register.component.ts:**

```
  getUsers() {
    this.memberService.getUsers().subscribe(data => {
      this.users = data;
    });
  }
```

Then use like you wrote

```
<ul>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let user of users$ | async ">
    <li>
      {{user._id}}  <-- For example user name
    </li>
  </ng-container>
</ul>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your solution. `{{user._id}}` worked, but I couldn't access data deeper in the object. For instance, when I tried `{{user.authData[0].username.value}}` (I got console error:  `TypeError: "_v.context.$implicit.authData[0] is undefined"`). Any ideas on that? Tks!

Comment: what is the reson of this `.pipe(map(data => data));}`

Comment: @malbarmawi We can map (transform) the response so the observable only return the "property" that we need. Not the whole object. Sorry  it was a late and fast response :D

Comment: @DragosLupei yes you are correct but `.pipe(map(data => data));}` there is no transformation here may uou mean this `.pipe(map(data => data.authData));}` 

Comment: but in that case we will lose the user data so user._id will be undefined 

Comment: @DragosLupei you are right I got your point the question somehow don't have all the information , good job 

Answer (score 1):

base of your data sample you can get the authData data like this

```
<ul>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let user of users ">
        <li >
            user id {{user._id}} , authData length {{user.authData.length}}
            userName <span *ngFor="let auth of user.authData">  {{auth.userName }}</span>
        </li>
    </ng-container>
</ul>
```

[**demo ⚡⚡**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pvzhp7)

Comment: Many thanks. I tried that, but unfortunately, it didn't work. There were no errors, but no data came through in the template. (it was just blank)

Comment: check I have create a mock data of this demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pvzhp7

Comment: Many thanks. Somehow, is your data different from the json data returned from `Express` using `res.json`? I can see it works in your `stackblitz` example, but for some reason, I still can't get it to work in my example with `json` data returned through the `http.get` call.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can; by the way Angular returns the object parsed to you; all you need is to have some object variable that contains the response; generally this object can be of type **any**, BUT you need first to subscribe to the response.

As an example that simulates some of your json to access it direclty

```typescript
getUsers() {
    this.member.getList().subscribe( resp => {
         this.users = resp;

         // To go through your json, you can use direct access like the following
         this.users.foreach(user => {
            let id = user['id'];                   // get the id
            let authData: [] = user['authData'];   // get authData list
         });

    })
}
```

And so on, this will allow you to parse dynamically instead of creating the model again in front-end. and as you have to know to access that from HTML you need to bind each object and replacing my code objects (id & authData) with them . Your code for this part in html after subscribing and assigning the result should work normally, also you can do nested loops without issue.

Comment: But while I can access `user['id']` this way, I still can't access `user[authData]` (undefined) or `user['authData'][0]` (I get message `TypeError: "user.authData[0] is undefined")`.

Comment: That means you didn’t get it in the response, you can use **debugger** keyword to check the actual values in runtime from the browser.

Comment: You're right! My Express back-end wasn't sending all the data I was expecting. I've straightened that out and your solution works great. Many thanks!